# Security for KeePass Emergencey Sheet

Tags: password-management, keepass, physical-access

[KeePass](https://keepass.info/news/n171012_2.37.html) just introduced the concept of an emergency sheet that can be shared with trusted users. This question might go beyond the scope of this site, but suppose you printed one of these sheets, how would you store it?

I found this [IS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/170689/evidence-of-any-large-scale-data-breaches-from-lack-of-physical-security) page, but I'm talking about the average house and the average person.

Suppose I printed the emergency sheet and allowed only my spouse or trusted member of my family access, what would be the ideal way of storing it to prevent unauthorized access? My guess would be a strong safe, I **doubt** a safety deposit box (my guess, anyone that can access your SDB, probably knows where you live).

After choosing secure storage for your sheet, how would you handle password policy, or changing your passwords periodically? You would have to print a new sheet, and properly destroy the old one.

Again, this question might go beyond the scope of this site, but before it's gets closed or put on hold, what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer lies in the question of what is the risks and threats?

A regular person, who doesn't have any specific threat to their safety/security likely is well served by having a fire and water-resistant personal safe (1-2 hour fire rating should cover most home fires).  This is where most people store a few items, like some emergency cash, passports, birth certificate, adoption papers, will, password sheet, etc.  A backup copy can be put in a SDB.

In this day, many people have 100-200 passwords for all of the sites we visit.  I think my list has about 300, since I use a long, complex, and random password, mother's maiden name, childhood friend, and those other reset questions - unique for every site.

I've had jobs where the ROOT passwords were all kept in a physical safe that was heavy TRTL 30x6, bolted down, in a locked room, locked floor, locked building.  That was policy.

In short, personally, I think that putting in the home's safe and SDB is a good idea for family COOP.

(Note.  If you are the type of person who would be the victim on a tv show, you might consider stronger measures, like a TRTL 24x6, armed guard, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the likely risks. I would guess first and foremost is burglary, followed by fire and flood which might vary a bit more by location.

Whilst a good home safe offers a decent level of protection against all 3, if discovered it will be a target of thieves, who may try to steal the whole thing and open it later.

For regular people the risk of someone deliberately trying to obtain the physical key is incredibly low.

I would suggest keeping two copies. One perhaps in a certain book in an upstairs room, and another with a trusted friend or relative who doesn't live in the immediate vicinity.

A normal burglar is highly unlikely to steal your computer and then painstakingly rummage through all your books. A friend is highly unlikely to have unsupervised physical access to your password vault, as well as being the person you have deemed least likely to want to. Their remote location then protects against fire, flood or other natural disaster.